# PHP sort html table by headings called from csv file

Tags: php

I've got a csv file I only use some of the columns from the file and now I want to sort the HTML table by clicking on the heading of each column i want to be able to sort acceding and descending the info i use is in the form of an array

```
<?php
$datei = fopen("soom.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$count = $count ;
// opens countlog.txt to change new hit number
$datei = fopen("soom.txt","w");
fwrite($datei, $count);
fclose($datei);

$favcolor = $count;


echo "<font  color = 'green' size='5' face='Comic Sans MS'>";
switch ($favcolor) {
    case 1:
        echo "27 May 2017 - Volkskool Potchefstroom";
        break;
    case 2: 
    echo "17 June 2017 - President Klerksdorp";
         break;
    case 3:
        echo "29 July 2017 - Trails Stilfontein";
        break;
    case 4:
        echo "12 August 2017 - Schoonspruit Saamtrek";
        break;
    case 5:
        echo "26 August 2017 - Meiringspark Klerksdorp";
        break;
    case 6:
        echo "9 September 2017 - Rustenburg";
        break;
    case 7:
        echo "14/21 October 2016 - Matlosana Mall";
        break;
    case 8:
        echo "4 November 2017 - Stratvaal Klerksdorp";
        break;
    case 9:
        echo "25 November 2017 - Baillie Park Klerksdorp";
        break;
    default:
        echo "";
}

echo "<font  color = 'white' size='3' face='Arial'>";
echo  nl2br ("&nbsp; \n &nbsp; ");



$fp = fopen ( "tour.$count.csv" , "r" );
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 1000 , "," )) !== FALSE ) {
"<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$data[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data[10]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data[2]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data[3]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data[4]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data[7]."</td>";
    echo "/<tr>";
}
fclose ( $fp );
?>
```

Comment: why dont you use one of the many javascript libraries to do it? Fat client, skinny server.

Comment: Use dataTables. Simple, quick and solves your problem https://datatables.net/